# TypeError: can't pickle face_BasicFaceRecognizer objects

Tags: python, opencv, pickle

I want to store the trained object, however there is an error shown above. What should I do if I need to store this trained model?

```
fishface = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer() 
m = fishface.train(training_data, np.asarray(training_labels))
output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(fishface, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OpenCV bindings typically don't support pickling. You'll have to use built-in OpenCV serialization.

You can do `m.save("serialized_recognizer.cv2")` and at runtime, `m.load("serialized_recognizer.cv2")`, if `m` is an instantiated FaceRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used to store the trained object to my current working directory. Saves me the work of holding all training data along with my application and time spent on training the model each time.

```
recognizer1 = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer1.train(images, np.array(labels))
#save at the last of the program using:-
recognizer1.save('qwe.xml')
#load it later in a different program/instance using:-
recognizer1 = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer1.load('qwe.xml')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Please add more information and context. What does this code do and how does this answer the user's question? If you're going to make a code-only answer, the code needs to at least be well commented.